# Catching emails on a local server

Tags: email, local

This is something I've struggled with for years.

I build my web applications on a local development server as you would expect.

Normally I'm working off a Win03 server running IIS and also running WAMP for php applications.

A lot of my applications send emails for notifications etc.

Previously I used to use the mail server running on the server to test email functionality.

However a change in my internal firewall (firewall is not running on the server itself - it runs on a separate gateway to intercept all outgoing and incoming traffic from the net) now means that I can't send emails to external email accounts from my development server.

Is there an application that I could install on the server which would intercept all mails being generated by the server and drop them into a local mail account on the server so I do not need to actually send the emails to a live active email account?

Any thoughts on how other people manage this scenario would be greatly appreciated!

Ed

Comment: ahh cheers for the heads up Robert.